# Gitflow with Github setup

Tags: git, github, installation, git-flow, centralized

I was previously using GIT with unfuddle, however I'm looking at trying Gitflow with Github as the central repository. So far I have done the following so far:

- Create Github account and create repository within Github I.e website
- `cd /home/username/Downloads/` (on local machine)
- `wget -q –
  http://github.com/nvie/gitflow/raw/develop/contrib/gitflow-installer.sh
  –no-check-certificate`
- `sudo chmod a+x gitflow-installer.sh`
- `sudo chmod a+x gitflow-installer.sh`
- `cd /var/www/website/` (where the website files are)
- `git flow init`
- `git remote add origin git@github.com:username/website.git`
- `git add *`
- `git commit -am “initial commit”`

All files are now committed ready to push to the central repository.

Create SSH key using this tutorial - https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys

Now, I'm trying to push the files to the central respository, however although the files have been pushed I got the following errors:

**error: unable to create directory for .git/refs/remotes/origin/develop**

**error: Cannot lock the ref 'refs/remotes/origin/develop'.**

Any idea why? Is this the correct setup so far?

Comment: Is it because I didn't do `git config remote.origin.push refs/heads/master:refs/heads/master`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"unable to create directory for .git/refs/remotes/origin/develop" means there is a permission issue to write the remote reference in your local repo initialized in `/var/www/website/`.

In [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3605721/6309) for instance, the OP had to do a `sudo git push`.
`sudo` or `chown` are mentioned in "[Problems with first upload to github](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2406721/6309)".

On the remote side, as mentioned in "[uploading a repository to github fails says “permission denied”](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2503752/6309)", make sure to add your public ssh key to your GitHub repo.